npm i command throws warning how to fix it
This is the warnings I am getting for npm i command. Node modules directory is creating. When I do ng build it's throwing errors showing all the modules as shown in second image. What will be the issue? I updated the package.json as shown below.
{
  "name": "VYIJNLKM",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "test:coverage": "rimraf coverage && npm run test -- --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint ngx-admin-demo --fix",
    "lint:styles": "stylelint ./src/**/*.scss",
    "lint:ci": "npm run lint && npm run lint:styles",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs",
    "docs:serve": "compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs -s",
    "prepush": "npm run lint:ci",
    "release:changelog": "npm run conventional-changelog -- -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points --tsconfig \"./src/tsconfig.app.json\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "17.3.8",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/google-maps": "^17.3.10",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.8",
    "@nebular/auth": "13.0.0",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "13.0.0",
    "@nebular/security": "13.0.0",
    "@nebular/theme": "13.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^12.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.37.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "echarts": "5.5.1",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "howler": "^2.2.4",
    "html-to-pdfmake": "^2.5.10",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "ionicons": "7.4.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "lz-string": "^1.5.0",
    "nebular-icons": "1.1.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ngx-echarts": "18.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "pace-js": "1.2.4",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.10",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.77.8",
    "secure-ls": "^2.0.0",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "tinymce": "7.2.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.3",
    "typeface-exo": "1.1.13",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "17.3.8",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "17.3.8",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.25",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.5.2",
    "@types/d3-color": "3.1.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/howler": "^2.2.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.10",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "conventional-changelog-cli": "5.0.0",
    "husky": "9.0.11",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "protractor": "~3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "6.0.0",
    "stylelint": "16.6.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  }
}




Are you working in full standalone configuration or still using modules ? Did you performed the classical troubleshooting steps like: remove node_modules, clear cache, verify the cache, performing npm i with node > 20 ?

Yeah I did all the steps you mentioned still through error.If I  do npm ls I can see all the version and modules name in the list.

Remove the postinstall script from package.json.
Remove this:
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 es5 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points --tsconfig "./src/tsconfig.app.json""

Why was ngcc removed?

The removal of ngcc is the last step forward in the transition to Ivy. Since the introduction of Ivy in Angular 9, Angular developers have actively encouraged the community and library authors to switch to Ivy. With the release of Angular 16, this process has become final, and now all libraries must be compatible with Ivy.


The removal of ngcc simplifies the build process and reduces build time, as there is no need for additional code transformation. It also makes integration with other tools like Webpack easier and facilitates development and debugging, as there are no complexities associated with having two different library formats.


I tried after removing this line still  I am facing same error

@Priya Try removing package-lock.json and node_modules and trry a fresh install

I tried that also still facing same error.

@Priya are you taking about first screneshot or second?

First screenshot when I do npm i I am getting those warnings but still node_modules got created.Then I did ng build it's throwing errors as shown in second screenshot but I can able to see all the npm packages in node modules folder.

@Priya this is the fix for the first screenshot, I think you have an error in shared module, that is why are getting these errors, check the module, that has these nb components

let me check it

I checked all modules files, all nb components are added. Is this create a problem if we changed the target es2022 in tsconfig.base.json.
"target": "es2022",
"typeRoots": [
   "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
],
"plugins": [
  { "name": "tslint-language-service" }
]

}
}

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
